# Definition of a 'manipulated variable' in process control - what is a manipulated variable exactly?

Tags: control-engineering

I've gathered a lot of different details online - trying to understand exactly what they mean by 'manipulated variable'. So I only decided to finally ask about it here.

In one source - eg. at this link [here](https://processdesign.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Process_controls), it says "*Inputs can further be separated into disturbance inputs and **manipulated inputs**. **Manipulated variables** refer to the quantities that are directly adjusted to control the system*."

Ok ----- I can see the source started to mention 'manipulated inputs', and then magically in the next word refers to 'manipulated variables'. So I'm assuming manipulated inputs means the same thing as manipulated variables.

May I ask if manipulatED variables refers to ALL variables (entire set) that are 'allowed to be manipulated' (ie. manipul**ABLE** ?

Or does 'manipulated variable' mean that a system may have various variables that can all potentially be manipulated, but the 'manipulated variables' are subsets of the entire set of potentially manipulated variables?

For example, if the system has in *total* five potentially manipul**able** variables, and then I decide to 'fix' (make constant) three of those variables and then decide that the remaining two variables stay adjustable (and will be adjusted), then does this mean that there will be two manipulated variables (even though there are actually five potentially manipulable variables)?

My question is just about getting a proper understanding about what is a 'manipulated variable'. I so far assume it's not the entire set of 'manipulable' variables in the system, and so far assume it means only the variables that we are going to independently manipulate (and not keep fixed at the beginning).

Thanks very much all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Niels already gave a good answer, but to still put some focus on the difference between manipul**able** and manipul**ated** variable:

Imagine you have a process in which you can influence the flow rate of a fluid and the temperature of that fluid. Then you have 2 manipul**able** variables.

However, while developing your control strategy, you decide that it would be best to keep the flow rate constant and let the closed-loop controller directly adjust the temperature of the fluid. Now the temperature became a manipul**ated** variable, because it is literally directly manipulated, while the flow rate remains constant.

> but the 'manipulated variables' are subsets of the entire set of potentially manipulated variables?

Correct, maybe try to imagine the manipul**ated** variable more as a property of the controller, not the controlled system. Everything that a controller could potentially influence is manipul**able**, everything that it *actually*  influences as a result of your control strategy is manipul**ated**.

Comment: Very much appreciated OpREs! Thanks very much for your help as well here. In those chemical process control books, I see terms such as 'manipulated variable (ie. control valves)' ---- which is so vague. I'm much more confortable with what you mentioned - about manipulable variables that are fixed permanently shouldn't be considered as manipulated variables. Only the variables that are going to be independently manipulated (changing in time etc) by a controller will be considered as the manipulated variables. Thanks again OpRes!

Answer (score 1):

A process or machine which you wish to subject to automatic control is fully characterized by a set of *state variables* which may for example be the velocities of each inertance in the system plus the displacements of each compliance in the system.

The *control variable* is chosen from the state variable list or is derived from a combination of the state variables, and is the one which is *manipulated*. It may be the temperature of a tank of liquid, the pressure in a gas canister, the flow rate of hydraulic fluid through a pump, or the speed of an engine output shaft.

Comment: Niels! Thanks very much for helping out! I can see from your system - that one of the state variables are 'manipulated'. 
From this link here [link]https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjC8pm5q8fqAhUMxzgGHdgeDdMQFjALegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.che.utexas.edu%2Fcourse%2Fche360%2Flecture_notes%2Fchapter_1.ppt&usg=AOvVaw2S9a7py_3WOAXuyKABKJa4[/link] -- slide #4 mentions that the manipulated variable is an 'input' variable, and then proceeds to give an example on slide #8. Are 'manipulated variables' the "entire set" of manipulABLE input variables?

Comment: I do not know. I specialized in control systems theory in grad school but that was 45 years ago and the terminology and tools have changed significantly since then!

Comment: Niels! I know what you mean! I just appreciated a lot you responding already. It would just be nice if those terminology such as 'manipulated variable' could be just better defined in process control text books. It's not that we can't understand the terms - just the poor or lack of proper explanation from those sources. Thanks again Niels!